# Reduce overhead Gurobi Python getting and setting attributes

Tags: mixed-integer-programming, python, gurobi

I am using Gurobi 9.5.1 in Python 3.10. In the context of column generation I request the duals of the master problem and set them in the objective of the subproblem. This is done repeated times.

```
   duals = master.getAttr(GRB.Attr.Pi, master.getConstrs())
   subprob.setAttr("Obj", subprob.getVars(), duals)
```

Around 10% of the time spent is in performing these operations. The rest is basically the solving times of the master and subproblems combined.

Is there a way to reduce such overhead?

Comment: Cross posted at SO: [Reduce overhead Gurobi Python getting and setting attributes](https://stackoverflow.com/q/72357878/8239061)

Comment: Saving the constraints `constrs = master.getConstrs()` (the number of these normally stays the same in the context of column generation) and variables `vars = master.getVars()`, once at the beginning, then update `vars` as appropriate after generating columns. Then just use these instead of calling `getConstrs` and `getVars` every time. This should be significantly faster.